# Is there a way for workers in celery to tell the broker "don't send me the next message until I told you so"

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am creating an app where order of execution is important. My tasks involves persisting data on a db. I wanted to make sure that the next data on the queue will never be process until the current executing tasks have been committed successfully. If there's an exception just keep on retrying the current tasks. But I'm not sure how retry works in celery.

1. Does it requeue the message and put it in front of queue making sure this message will be executed first.

or

1. Give chance to the next messages in the queue and retry later.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [celery chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) is what you need.